# How do you override the tilda (~) resolution in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: asp.net-core, razor, razor-pages

In my ASP.NET Core 5 application, I use `~/` to resolve to the root of the content directory.

However, I've now switched to hosting all the static files on a CDN (uploading anything in `wwwroot` at build time).

Is there a way to modify the `~` resolution so that it gives me a path like `https://cdn.example.com/foo-asset` instead of `/foo-asset` like it normally does?

I tried setting the `IHostingEnvironment.WebRootPath` property, however that can't handle URLs, and it looks like it also does something different than what I want (it tells the server where to read static files from, instead of telling it where `~/` should resolve to)

Another option is to use a method to do the resolution wherever I use these paths, like `<a href=@ResolveCdn("~/foo-asset")>` but I would rather not do this if at all possible.

Comment: The tilde (~) in front of URLs means that these URLs point to the root of your web application. I don't think you can do something with it.

Comment: Why don't you hardcode the CDN Url? Is it likely to change?